# How to avoid useless else block statements to increase branch coverage in unit test cases?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, gulp, sonarqube, karma-jasmine

Considering the following code:

```
    function test(val){
        flag = val;        

        if (!flag) {
            doThis();
        }     
        createSomething();
   }
```

So, considering the unit test coverage, even the function statement is covered, the branches are not covered as else block doesn't exist. So the branches covered will be 50% and due to sonar issues, we will not be able to merge this to develop. So to get rid off this, useless code we write like `return false;` in the else block and make the script grow.

Is it efficient way of writing the code? Is there a way to avoid writing useless un-necessary codes just to make sure the coverage is 100%. This is a bad practise, need suggestions to get rid off this. Do we have any setting, so that we can update ignore `else` block statements and increase the coverage if not defined.

Sonar forces to write else block:

[image]

I have 100% code coverage, but the branch coverage is 50% just because of ignoring the else block. There are sonar rules defined if not more than 80%, we could not merge the code :(

Comment: Why would you need to add an else block to improve coverage? Just test your function with a truthy val, and with a falsy val, and everything will be covered.

Comment: We can't see your tests, but if you have one that checks `doThis` is called for `!flag` and one that checks it isn't for `flag`, then you should see full coverage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need extra code, you just have make sure you call `test(true)` and `test(false)` and the test should show 100% branch coverage for that function